# Are states from an unpolarized source beam distinguishable or not

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I have seen this pop up twice so far in my reading of Feynman Lectures III. For example, in the first equation of [section 5-8](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/III_05.html#Ch5-S8) (it may take up to a minute for the equation to load), where the beam is ejected from a furnace and so states are randomly produced, the probablities are added rather than first interfering the probability amplitudes and taking absolute-squared. But I thought nothing was done to distinguish the states $+S, 0S, -S$.

Moreover, in the situation of the fancy "extended" Stern-Gerlach apparatus where I split the beam into three beams according to the $S$ states but recombine them without blocking any of the split beams, I perform future calculations by interfering the three amplitudes. I am convinced here that I have to do interference. But why is the first paragraph different?